# How to unlink a framework on program start

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, linker, dropbox

I am developing for iPhone OS 3.1.3 and I need to use Dropbox API.

The problem is the Dropbox API requires at least iOS 4.2. Ok.

I decided to save the possibility of using the program under 3.1.3, but if it is 4.2 and higher, there will be Dropbox functionality.

To use Dropbox framework I needed to link another frameworks:

- Security.framework
- QuartzCore.framework

I have done this.

When I link Dropbox.framework to my project, the program works great on iPhone Simulator, but it cannot be started on my iPhone 3.1.3. There is an error in Output:

---

dyld: Symbol not found: _kSecAttrAccessible
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/C1FC10E5-0A36-4DEB-BD27-5028C205C89D/Bus Time.app/Bus Time
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
 in /var/mobile/Applications/C1FC10E5-0A36-4DEB-BD27-5028C205C89D/Bus Time.app/Bus Time

---

So the question is:

Can I detect the iOS version on the program start and unlink the framework? 
Or could you offer an another way to use dropbox for 3.1.3?

Thank you for your answers. I appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you targeting 3.x? The number of iOS devices still running 3.x is incredibly tiny. About year ago, 3.x was running on only ~11% of iOS devices. That was well before 5.x, and 6.x is right around the corner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Just because of I am using iPhone first Gen. This one has an incredible design and it has been working well for me more than 4 years. I know it is time to buy new 4S, but not now. I need to develop something first.

Comment: You cannot programmatically unlink something at runtime. You have to do it the other way around, programmatically link it if possible—which also means programmatically accessing classes and selectors and/or C symbols. Often, you can use weak framework linking to make the runtime do all the hard stuff for you, so the only part left you have to do manually is check symbols for null before using them. The right answer depends on whether you want pointers to weak linking so you can try it that way, or whether you know that won't work and want to know how to load dynamically.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. My knowledges about dynamic linking are not great, really. I'll try to learn more about it.

I have tried to mark these frameworks as Optional (Project - Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries) , after that my Bus Time successfully started on my iPhone.

Comment: I've tried to do the same with dropbox example application. Start - ok. Give a try to use dropbox api functionality - crash! As expected.
Simulator runs this well. So the simulator has a linked framework, iPhone hasn't. So my problem is solved!

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're weak linking the entire framework, which is good. That means at runtime, you can check whether the symbols you want are null, and make sure to avoid calling them if they are, and that should be all you need. If not, ask again.

Comment: Yeah! At runtime I am checking the running iOS version. If it isn't capable with DropboxAPI, I ignore all the buttons, view controllers and classes, that uses it.

Comment: It's generally better to check for specific functionality, instead of checking for OS version and then assuming the functionality on that basis. But sometimes—especially for non-Apple frameworks—that isn't possible, in which case what you're doing is exactly right.

Comment: Do you mean it is better to use "responds to selector" method?

Comment: P.S. I've done my App as course assignment in my Uni. It works fine, and I am happy :) Maybe it'll come to AppStore as free, I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, the details for how to check depend on what you're checking. respondsToSelector (or instancesRespondToSelector) is necessary when you want to use a class that exists in both 3.x and 4.x, but has a new message in 4.x that you want to call. But there are other cases—the class doesn't even exist in 3.x's framework, the whole framework doesn't exist in 3.x, you're dealing with a C API rather than ObJC, etc. Apple's guide on weak linking is pretty detailed, and covers all the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot programmatically unlink a framework at runtime.

You can programmatically *link* a framework at runtime, e.g. by using the NSBundle APIs, or dlopen, or various other ways. If you do so, you have to then manually load the ObjC objects and/or C symbols you want.

Alternatively, you can weak-link the framework, which makes the runtime do most of the work for you. If it's there, it will be loaded in at startup, and all of its ObjC objects and C symbols will be available to you. Otherwise, all of its ObjC objects and C symbols will be null. So, all you have to do is check for null to decide whether to run the code that needs that framework.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the Security framework in your file list.
2. Expand the right sidebar (View > Utilities > Show Utilities).
3. Under 'Target Membership' change 'Required' to 'Optional.'